How to prove $\forall p\in\left(\frac12,1\right)\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac1{k+1} \binom{2k}k p^k (1-p)^k \right) \le \frac1p$?

How to prove $\forall m\ge0\quad\forall p\in\left(\frac12,1\right)\quad\sum_{k=0}^m \left( \frac1{k+1} \binom{2k}k p^k (1-p)^k \right) \le \frac1p$?

Since this has to be true for all $m$ then it's equivalent to proving that the same identity where $m$ is replaced with infinity holds. I tried a few methods like using the fact that $\binom{2k}k\le4^k$ and then overestimating to a geometric sum and overestimating to a sum of the form $\frac1x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} (1)$ but both of these failed because as $p$ approaches $\frac12$ both of these overestimations go to infinity. I tried graphing this with desmos and it appears to hold for m up to 200. This is for a university entrance exam so it shouldn't use topics that are too advanced, though its allowed to use well-known identities that can only be proven with advanced knowledge.

This answer says that your $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dots\le\frac1p$ is actually an $=$

Does this answer your question? Generating function satisfying a second degree equation See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof, and some of the posts in this list.

Are you suppoed to knwo about the Gaussian hypegeomtric function ?

Does this answer your question? Random walks with finite chance of escape

@ThànhNguyễn: your link is probably above the types of things required for college entry level admissions.

This problem can be solved using the binomial power series. Set $x=p(1-p)$ so that your series takes the form
$$ f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} x^n$$
This is the generating function of $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.
Recall that for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$$
where
$$\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}$$
In general, the series converges for $-1<x\leq 1$.
Through some algebraic manipulation, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}{(n!)^2}\\
&=\frac12\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)(2n+2)}{((n+1)!)^2}\\
&=\frac12\frac{2^{n+1}\, (n+1)!\, 1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots \cdot(2n-1)}{((n+1)!)((n+1)!))}\\
&=\frac12\frac{2^{n+1}\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots \cdot(2n-1)}{(n+1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\frac12\frac{2^{n+1}(-1)\cdot(1-2)\cdot (1-4)\cdot \ldots\cdot(1-(2n-2))\cdot(1-2n)}{(n+1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\frac12\frac{4^{n+1}(-1)\cdot(\tfrac12-1)\cdot (\frac12-2)\cdot \ldots\cdot(\tfrac12-(n-1))\cdot(\tfrac12-n)}{(n+1)!}\\
&=-\frac12(-1)^{n+1}\binom{\tfrac12}{n+1}4^{n+1}
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
f(x)&=-\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^{n+1}\binom{\tfrac12}{n+1}4^{n+1}x^n\\
&=-\frac{1}{2x}\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n}\binom{\tfrac12}{n}4^{n}x^n\\
&=-\frac1{2x}\big((1-4x)^{1/2}-1\big)=\frac{1-(1-4x)^{1/2}}{2x}
\end{align}
Since $0<p(1-p)\leq \frac14$, $f(p(1-p))$ is well defined and
$$f(p(1-p))=\frac{1-(1-4p+4p^2)^{1/2}}{2p(1-p)}=\frac{1-|2p-1|}{2p(p-1)}$$
Your conjecture follows form this.

Nice solution and (+1). Can you work the partial sum without invoking the Gaussian hypergeometric function ?

Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici! I know how to do it only through probabilistic arguments (tossing an unfair coin till number of heads and tails are the same kind of think) which probably not much more transparent.

Then, please do it ! It is very interesting. I have a solution and an asymptotic but they are based on  the Gaussian hypergeometric function
